# Anychart 8 - Datetime value is getting rounded off in tooltip

Tags: anychart

I am facing this issue that when I hover on a point in anychart spline/colume graphs, then the crosshair label on x axis(datetime scale x axis) is showing me the rawvalue and i am able to format that to minutes format. But at same point, my tooltip is giving me x value with rounded off to hours only. Why its happening and how can we resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid inaccurate date output, you could use [text formatters](https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Text_Formatters), as shown below

```
var tooltip = chart.tooltip();
tooltip.title().text("Title");
chart.tooltip().format('{%x}{dateTimeFormat:d MMMM \'\'yy HH:mm}');
```

And in the sample here: https://playground.anychart.com/HPjfaiYh/2